# Add research into announcement in Liferay search plugin

Tags: liferay

I'm using the search plugin of Liferay 6.1, 
but I noted that the news inserted in the announcement Liferay plugin are never in the search result, I added into the plugin configuration, in facets: `com.liferay.portlet.announcements.model.AnnouncementsEntry` but nothing change,

Someone know if is it the correct liferay class to add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tracked the code and found that the Announcements are not indexed in Liferay, please have a look at

> com.liferay.portlet.announcements.service.impl.addEntry()

There is no indexer calling code here, but look at

> com.liferay.portlet.bookmarks.service.impl.addEntry()

Here there is a bookmark indexer class which is responsible to store data for searching.

Now, in order to get the Announcements in search, you need to create an indexer, just like the bookmarks and then you will get the same in Liferay search portlet.